# How do I get bootstrap carousel to slide?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

my carousel will not change slides. The actual carousel will open on my site, but I am unable to click the right or left indicators to change to a different slide. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I've tried changing my java script commands. I've tried deleting and restarting my carousel, but no luck.

```js
("carousel").carousel();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html lang="en">

  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/restaurantStyles.css" />

  <script>

  </script>
    <style>

      </style>


    </head>
    <body onload="alert('This website is best viewed with JavaScript enabled. Please check your settings to ensure JavaScript is enabled before proceeding');">
      <div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">

     
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 400px;">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/newLoc.png" alt="newLoc">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Seasonal.png" alt="Seasonal Menu">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/drink.png" alt="SG Brew">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
        </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q81/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>



<footer>
  <hr />
  <p> 305 Gray Street, Houston, TX, 77004 <br />
    713-555-6752</p>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the console output, on clicking the arrows

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple example of bootstrap carousel that you can refer

Codepen Link: [Click me](https://codepen.io/bhavik103/pen/WNbrxxz)

```css
h2{
    margin: 0;     
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 90px;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-family: "trebuchet ms", sans-serif;    
}

.item{
    background: white;    
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px !important;
}

.carousel{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .item {
  opacity:0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* ie fix */
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.item {
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* ie fix */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="6500" data-ride="carousel">
     <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   
       <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>First slide label</h3>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                  <p>Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 3</h2>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                  <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery '$' along with `#` to call `carousel()` functions;

Replace `("carousel").carousel();` with `$("#carousel").carousel();`

Comment: For some reason, this is still not letting my carousel move from the first slide. I've tried in .js as well as on my html page under <script>

Answer (score 0):

first of all remove `("carousel").carousel();` from your code this is not required.

and second one is that you need to complete your two `</div>` before `</body>` complete.

and third one is you have to define footer inside of your `body` right now it is outside of your body.

and the last one you have to use the proper online CDNs for all external files right now it gives error.

follow the below snippet for more understanding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Demo Page</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="alert('This website is best viewed with JavaScript enabled. Please check your settings to ensure JavaScript is enabled before proceeding');">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
   <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 400px;">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/newLoc.png" alt="newLoc">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Seasonal.png" alt="Seasonal Menu">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/drink.png" alt="SG Brew">
     </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
  <hr />
  <p> 305 Gray Street, Houston, TX, 77004 <br />
  713-555-6752</p>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this answer will fulfill your all requirements and helpful to solve your problem.

Thank you...